# how to update database table through solr

Tags: mysql, xml, solr

I am fetching data from MySql database to solr server, my point is can i run update command?
My db-data-config.xml file is as :

```
<document name="d1"> 
     <entity name="torder" query="update  torder set price='7777.00' where UID_PK='13142'">
        </entity>
    </document>
```

when I run command to index data then it throws an exception saying unable to executequery "update  torder set price='7777.00' where UID_PK='13142'", I want to know is it possible to run update here.please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting, but is unlikely to work as solr should expecting some data to be returned by the query (the data then will be used for constructing the solr document fields)

if putting update statement into a stored procedure,
with given correct access right,
probably can do this - `call simpleproc (7777.00, 13142);`

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN id INT, IN price DOUBLE)
BEGIN
  UPDATE element SET torder price=val WHERE UID_PK=id;
  SELECT * FROM torder_price WHERE UID_OK=id;
END//
```